# Parenthesis issue in codeigniter url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

Few of my project urls contains the parenthesis and it is a codeigniter project. Unfortunately I cant remove them.
So I am writing following rules in my route.php of config folder:

```
$route['abc-(def)'] = 'locations/index/12492';
$route['abc-%28def%29'] = 'locations/index/12492';
$route['404_override'] = 'home/pagenotfoundhandler';
```

So when I am trying to access URL http://mydomain.com/abc-(def) or http://mydomain.com/abc-%28def%29 it takes me to home/pagenotfoundhandler, while it should take me to location controller and index method. Please suggest how to deal with parenthesis in codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses are a part of the regex pattern, so try escaping them if you want to use them as ascii characters like this:

```
$route['abc-\(def\)'] = 'locations/index/12492';
```

And one more place to look:

There should be a allowed uri characters setting in config.php for your codeigniter system. check there if parentheses are allowed.

Alternatively, you can disable `$config["csrf_protection"]` to skip url xss cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess that is because the page `http://mydomain.com/abc-(def)` which is supposed to redirect to `locations/index/12492` can not be found! so a `404 - Page not Found` error takes place, which of course as you have defined takes you to `home/pagenotfoundhandler`! make sure the path exists or even why do not you give the complete path to see if it works!